# How do I validate an association value is present in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

I want to validate `user.company.aum_id`. I have

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :company
  validates_associated :company
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :company, :image

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
  validates :aum_id, presence: true, if: 'user.provider?'
```

But it keeps giving this error in my tests

> NoMethodError (undefined method `provider?' for nil:NilClass):

I don't want to paper over the error with `user && user.provider?`. How can I check that the associated record has the value, but only when the user method `#provider?` is true? It's as if company.user is not set. It works fine and the values save without the validator.

I thought about adding a custom validator in User but it looks like you can only specify symbols in the same model.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods

---

I tried

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates_with AumValidator
```

`app/validators/aum_validator.rb`  ??? path ???

```
class AumValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(user)
    if user.provider? && user.company.aum_id.blank?
      user.errors[:aum_id] << 'Assets Under Management is required.'
    end
  end
end
```

But it gives the error

> uninitialized constant User::AumValidator

Rails 5.0.6

Comment: No need to write `dependent: :destroy` for belongs_to . it is only used for has many and has one

Comment: user will not be created at the time when campany is being created.so you can try once by adding this to your creat action before save <pre > <@company = @company.build_user> and in view also to add the user, then this validation will work as you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using custom validation

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :company_aum_id_present, if: :provider?

  private def company_aum_id_present
    self.errors[:aum_id] << 'Assets Under Management is required.' if company && company.aum_id.blank?
  end
end
```

Also When usin custom validator you dont need to include `ActiveModel::Validations` as it is already included by `ApplicationRecord`

Comment: OK that works. I didn't think you could add errors for a field that didn't exist in the model (`:aum_id`). Now it is giving the wrong error: "Aum Assets Under Management is required.". And it is not highlighting the field in red. How do I fix those?

Comment: try using `self.errors[:"company.aum_id"]` instead of `self.errors[:aum_id]`

Comment: That works for the message. That didn't work for wrapping the field with `field_with_error`. I also tried `:user_company_attributes_aum_id`, `:company_attributes_aum_id`, `:"company_attributes.aum_id"`, `"company.aum_id"`, etc. See related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175148/how-do-i-mark-a-missing-required-field-with-field-with-errors-in-an-associated-r?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -2):

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :user
  validates :user
  validates :aum_id, presence: true, if: -> { user.provider? }
end
```

Having the `->` (lambda) in the validate method makes it so it is evaluated every time the validation is run.

This assumes that the `User` implements a `provider?` method or has an attribute named `provider`.

It also requires that `Company` has a `User`.